# google maps customizing marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, svg

```
I am new to google Maps,and planning to use customized marker which will have
arrow pointer surrounded with circle icon based on the movement I want to rotate 
marker.
```

As mentioned in the documentation for customizing the markers, I can use the SVG path as marker notation. and here is my SVG inline code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg height="210" width="500">
  <circle cx="14" cy="11" r="9" stroke-width="2" fill="#8dc73f" />
  <line x1="14" y1="16" x2="14" y2="6" style="stroke: white;stroke-width:2" />
  <line x1="10" y1="10" x2="14" y2="6" style="stroke: white;stroke-width:2" />
  <line x1="18" y1="10" x2="14" y2="6" style="stroke: white;stroke-width:2" />
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

I have no idea to generate an path for the above SVG code. Google Markers will strictly accept only the PATH.

```
Is there any way I can generate a path for the SVG inline code.
```

OR

```
Is there any other possible approach I can customize the marker in the HTML 
content and render into the map?
```

Comment: Actually I have no idea how to convert into path..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line elements can be converted to path data using a moveto (M) command and a lineto (L) command. For example, d="M x1 y1 L x2 y2".

Circle elements can be converted to path data using a moveto (M) command and two elliptical arc (A) commands. For example, d="M cx (cy-r) A r r 0 1 0 cx (cy+r) A r r 0 1 0 cx (cy-r)". In other words, you can break the circle into two half circle arcs.

Note that you can not draw a full circle with a single elliptical arc (A) command because if the end points of the arc were identical then there would be an infinite number of possible arcs that satisfy the remaining parameters to the elliptical arc (A) command.

In your example, the circle element and three line elements could be converted into a single path using d="M 14 2 A 9 9 0 1 0 14 20 A 9 9 0 1 0 14 2 M 14 16 L 14 6 M 10 10 L 14 6 M 18 10 L 14 6".

Note that in your example, the circle element and line elements have different fill and stroke attributes. If you replace the circle element and line elements with a single path then the resulting path can only have a single fill and a single stroke.